# weblogic 12c and jersey integration

Tags: spring, jersey, weblogic12c

I am using a web project on weblogic 12c and jersey

my app depends on spring framework for business logic

do I need jersey-spring integration? if not what will my Rest Resource look like?
how do I get the context / spring beans from REST layer?

what does jersey-spring give me? also what is the difference between jersey-spring 1.17.1 and jersey-spring3? I am using jersey 1.17.1 with spring 4.1.5

edit: I am not using spring mvc,
I am writing REST services,
UI dude is writing angular js based stuff

Comment: i have no problem running spring boot in weblogic 12c, spring boot is using jersey 1.9.x to initiate its @RestController

Comment: @IanLim A `@RestController` has nothing to do with Jersey, `@RestController` is using the Spring MVC stuff and not JAX-RS, those are 2 completely different things!.